# React tutorial not displaying the div

Tags: reactjs

Im a started with Reactjs and built my initial div but for some reason it does not display the div.

Here is the code displayed

[image]

helloworld.js content:

```
React.render(
    React.createElement('h1',null,'Hello World')
    ,document.getElementById('divContainer')
    )
```

Console error:

react.render is not a function.

React version used:

```
React v15.0.1
```

Comment: Did you include `import React from "react";` statement in your hello-world.js

Comment: import React from "react" , once I add this line I get "Unexpected token import" error

Comment: When I got this error, for me React was not configured properly. I later used webpack dev server to run it and it worked correctly then.

Comment: I think you are not transpiling your es6 files into es5. `import` is not functional in any browser yet, so you have to use transpiler like for example `Babel`. Besides, don't use `React.render` for your root component, instead use `ReactDOM.render` from `react-dom` lib.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ReactDOM.render() function

Comment: Do you know *why*? Or are you just fishing for +1's with [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685689/react-tutorial-not-displaying-the-div#comment60961051_36685689) without any explanation?

Comment: Cause render method is available in reactDOM and not in react

Answer (score 0):

You need to import React like so:
`import React from 'react';`

You need to import the library called React. Also, `React.render()` is deprecated, you need to use `ReactDOM.render()`.

To take a component and render it to the DOM has been a separate library called `ReactDOM`. You don't use React with `render()`, you use `ReactDOM`. In order to use it you also have to import it like so:

`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Then you can implement:

`ReactDOM.render(App);`

But that is not all. You have not shown us the whole code to your component, but you need to instantiate your component before rendering. What you showed seems to be the transpiled version from Babel, but even that seems not quite right, it would look like this:

```
    var App = function App() {
    return React.createElement(
        "h1",
        null,
        "Hello World"
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null));
```

And the above code would be based off creating an instance of `App`.

This is a class: `App` of a component, it produces instances. To make an instance, you just wrap it in jsx tags like soL `<App />`.

Last but not least you need to put it in the page or DOM via the second argument which is a target container. When you render the component `<App />`, produce some HTML into this element that exists in our HTML document, so then your code, going by your transpiled version that you shared here would look like this:

```
var App = function App() {
    return React.createElement(
        'h1',
        null,
        'Hello World'
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.querySelector('.container'));
```